# Неправильно работает скрипт jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript

```
$("#cat_url").focus(function() {
    if($(this).val("")) $(this).val("http://");
}).blur(function() {
    if($(this).val("http://")) $(this).val("");
});
```

Смысл прост. Как только фокусимся на инпуте, то проверяем что в нем написано. Если ничего, то добавляем значение "http://". При блуре, скажем, если значение осталось "http://", тобишь пользователь ничего не ввел, сносим все из поля.

Первая часть при фокусе работает отлично, но вот при блуре поле отчищается во всех случаях, чтобы в нем не было написано. Как исправить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы понимаете, как работает функция `val()`?

Если функция не содержит значения (`$(this).val()`), то она отдаст значение поля.

Если функция содержит значение (`$(this).val("")`), то она установит это значение полю.

Comment: а как верно тогда?

Comment: @inferus-vv 

`
    $("#cat_url").focus(function() {
        if($(this).val() == "") $(this).val("http://");
    }).blur(function() {
        if($(this).val() == "http://") $(this).val("");
    });
`

Comment: `$(this).val() == ""` эквивалентно `!$(this).val()`

Comment: Спасибо. Работает) А возможно запретить стирать этот текст. Т.е. http:// будет всегда, остальное, что напишет пользователь, можно редактировать.

Comment: вешаем onkeyup, смотрим, сколько символов содержит поле. Если меньше 7, то просто вставляем http://

Comment: вариант хорош, но пользователь может выделить весь текст и с пом ctrl+v вставить совершенно иной длиной более 7 символов. Да, конечно будет валидация на стороне сервера, но все же..

Comment: я бы вообще не парился и добавил картинку вместо надписи.

Comment: Можно так тогда: http://jsfiddle.net/UsfDH/3/